# How to convert "curl -X POST -T " to Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

How do I convert

```bash
curl -X POST -T 'sample_data.json' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://sample_url.com
```

to Python using `requests`?

Specifically, how do I provide "-T" parameter to the request?

Comment: Try https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
import requests
import json

requests.post('https://sample_url.com', 
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}, 
    data = json.loads(open('sample_data.json').read())
}
```

You can check out the [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) page for more details.

Or, to show a fully self-contained example without having to load the json from a file, you could do:

```
import requests
requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
<Response [200]>
```

Note, from the requests docs:

> Using the `json` parameter in the request will change the `Content-Type` in the header to `application/json`.

So, you could just do the following instead:

```
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Comment: The header definition isn't needed actually. Requests will automatically put it in there if you use the json parameter, helps to simplify the request

Comment: @huma474 -- thank you. I just looked that up and added it to the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the Python Requests library - https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/. To be able to post a JSON payload in the message is

```
import Requests
import json
result = requests.post(URL,json=json.loads(open('sample_data.json').read()))
```

The requests library natively understands how to send your JSON data

There are some more examples of how to post messages with Form encoded payloads on this part of the page as well - https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

To be able to do other verbs you just need to change the function for requests -

```
for a GET, requests.get(url)
for a PUT, requests.put(url,data=DATA) or requests.put(url,json=JSON)
for a DELETE, requests.delete(url)
```

and so on.

Comment: in my case POST request invokes PUT operation and I need to provide "-T" parameter. How can I do it?

Comment: `json.loads("foo.txt")` loads the literal *string* `"foo.txt"`, not the file.

Comment: The `json` parameter just lets you avoid explicitly calling `json.dumps` to encode a Python value. You already *have* JSON-encoded data, so there's no point in decoding it only to re-encode it. Just use `data=open('...').read()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST -T 'sample_data.json' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     https://sample_url.com/
```

is effectively equivalent to

```
curl -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d "$(cat sample_data.json)" \
     https://sample_url.com/sample_data.json
```

so using `requests`, it would be

```
with open('sample_data.json') as fh:
    response = requests.post(
        "https://sample_url.com/sample_data.json",
        data=fh.read(), 
        header={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you could do it. But the best way is to use the [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library. It's not part of the standard library (yet), but makes HTTP requests super straight-forward.

```
$ pip install requests
```

or

```
$ conda install requests
```

Then

```
import json

import requests

url = r"https://sample_url.com"
with open("sample_data.json", "r") as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)
requests.post(url=url, data=data)
```